# Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, jboss

I deployed my project to the server sucssusfuly, But when I'm sending requests I get 404 or method is not allowed. On the jboss panel the project is running, But I can't send any requests to it ?.

When I checked the server logs I found these errors:

```
2022-11-29 12:59:17,796 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 564) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:02:44,170 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 585) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:02:44,170 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 585) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:23:50,811 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 597) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:23:50,812 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 597) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:26:04,650 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 613) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:26:04,651 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 613) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:34:10,409 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 625) Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2022-11-29 13:34:10,410 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 625) Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
```

my POM.xml:

```
     <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!--        <exclusion>-->
            <!--          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
            <!--        </exclusion>-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
<!--        <exclusion>-->
<!--          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
<!--        </exclusion>-->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>-->
<!--      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>-->
<!--      <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>-->
<!--      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>-->
<!--      <version>2.4</version>-->
<!--      <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <!--        <exclusion>-->
        <!--          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
        <!--        </exclusion>-->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
<!--            <exclusion>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>-->
<!--            </exclusion>-->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
  <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Note:

I think somthing is wrong with my pom.xml file but I can't find what is the problem since it's my first time to deploy.

Comment: You need to add javax.annotation-api to your pom

Comment: What does this have to do with JBoss?